# Creating image on Python

Tags: python, image, png

I don't know why my program doesn't work. I've tried to save it on my pc but it continues to give me error `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Here is my code:

```
import png
from IPython.display import Image
def create(iw, ih, c=(0,0,0)):
    img=[]
    for _ in range(ih):
       row=[]
       for _ in range(iw):
          row.append(c)
      img.append(iw)
    img=create(128,128)
    save('prova.png',img)
```

Comment: Because of indendation you call `create` inside `create`. Or is this an formatting error in your post?

Comment: no it isn't , so i have to put "create" out of the main function? or just change the function name?

Comment: Try putting the last two lines on the same indentation level as import.

Comment: now no errors, but nothing happens, there is no "prova.png" image on my computer

Comment: You may check the current working directory. add `import os` (e.g. right after `import png` and add `print os.getcwd()` (python 2.x) or print(os.getcwd())` (python 3.x) after `save` to see where your program write the image. If this does not help, this would probably result in a new question.